# Angular 6: Send click event in child to parent

Tags: angular, events, nested, click, parent-child

**EDIT:
It still don't work and not throw any errors.
I edited the code and added partial code from parent.component.ts**

I have parent component of a side nav-bar and child component which is nested in parent component's body and contains iframe.
I want that when there's a click event on the iframe, I'll return to the parent that event has occurred so I can mark this video as watched in the parent's sidebar with a 'V'.

**parent component.ts**

```js
// ..... 

export class CoursePlayComponent implements OnInit {
    course: ICourse;
    courseId: number;

    // current user
    public currentUser: IUser;

    // variables for current lesson
    public current: IVideo;
      
    constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private userService: UserService) {
         this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      }
       
    ngOnInit() {
     // save this course id from course-detail and get http request from the service
     this.courseId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("courseId"));
     this.getCourse(this.courseId);
    }
    
    // get course by id from service
    getCourse(id:number) {...}
    
    // get current lesson by unit and lesson position in course
    getCurrent(unit_position: number, lesson_position: number) { ... }
    
    // check if the lesson already watched
    isLessonIncluded(course_id: number, lesson_id: number) {
      return this.userService.isLessonIncluded(course_id, lesson_id);
    }
  
    // check the value from child lesson and add the new lesson to the completed lessons array
    watched(state) {
      console.log("parent-video watched: ", state);
      
      // update user data array
      this.userService.addToCompletedLessons(this.course.id, this.current.id);
    }   
 }
```

**parent.component.html:**

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen *ngIf="course">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
    <mat-toolbar id="sidenav" color="primary">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="mat-icon-button sidenav-toggle-button" [hidden]="!sidenav.opened">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Menu" class="material-icons">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let unit of course.units">
        <h6 class="course-list-title">Unit {{ unit?.position }}: {{ unit?.name }}</h6>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let lesson of unit.videos" class="sidenav-link course-item" [routerLink]="['/courses' , course?.id , 'unit' , unit?.position , 'lesson' , lesson?.position]" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" (click)="getCurrent(unit?.position,lesson?.position)">
          <span mat-line class="title">Lesson {{lesson?.id}}: {{lesson?.name}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="isLessonIncluded(course.id, lesson.id)" class="fas fa-check" style="color:lightgreen;"></span>
        </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

<!-- ... -->

    <div class="course-body container-fluid text-center">
      <course-lesson *ngIf="showLesson == true" (clicked)="watched($event)" [lessonId]="current?.id" [lessonName]="current?.name" [lessonData]="current?.data" [totalLesoons]="totalLesoons"></course-lesson>
   
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**child.component.ts:**

```js
// ....

export class CourseLessonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() lessonId: number;
  @Input() lessonName: string;
  @Input() lessonData: string;
  @Input() totalLesoons: number;
  
  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();

  clicked: boolean = false;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
  
    watchedVideo() {
    console.log("child- video watched");
      this.clicked.emit(true);
  }
}
```

**child.component.html:**

```html
<h1 class="lesson-title">{{lessonName}}</h1>
  <p class="small-text" *ngIf="totalLesoons > 0">lesson {{lessonId}} of {{totalLesoons}}</p>
  <hr>
  <iframe (click)="clicked = true" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" [src]='lessonData | safe'></iframe>
```

Comment: use an output in the child component

Comment: How? I tried use some examples I saw on stuckoverflow but none worked

Comment: pretty much the same way you use the inputs, googling `angular @output()` should be enough

Comment: ```@Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<void>();```
```addLesson(): void { this.clicked.next(); }```
```<iframe (click)="addLesson($event)" ... >```

Comment: and it's update immediately the parent? what do I write in the ngIf for showing the 'V'?

Answer (score 8):

You can leverage of `@Output` & `@EventEmitter` to notify your parent component through child component.

### Child component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { CourseService } from '../../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'course-lesson',
  templateUrl: './course-lesson.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-lesson.component.sass']
})
export class CourseLessonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() lessonId: number;
  @Input() lessonName: string;
  @Input() lessonData: string;
  @Input() totalLesoons: number;
  @Output() paused = new EventEmitter<string>();

  pauseClick(){
    this.paused.emit(true);
  }

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

### Child Component html

```
<iframe (click)="pauseClick()" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" [src]='lessonData | safe'></iframe>
```

### Parent Component HTML

```
<course-lesson (paused)="onPausedClick($event)" *ngIf="showLesson == true" [lessonId]="current?.id" [lessonName]="current?.name" [lessonData]="current?.data" [totalLesoons]="totalLesoons"></course-lesson>
```

### Parent Component ts

```
public pauseState = false;
onPausedClick(state){
   console.log("Paused is clicked ", state);
   this.pauseState = state;
}
```

Comment: thanks! I want to add also ngIf in the sidebar that will show (or not) a v font if paused is true. to so I need to write in this tag *ngIf="onPauseClick()" for that?

Comment: If you have sidebar in parent component then you can add put `*ngIf="!pauseState "`. I have updated the answer as well. Just check if it meets your requirement.

Comment: it's not working for me. I edited the code so you can see what I changed. there isn't any errors too.

Comment: Could you put the `console.log` in `onPausedClick` and `pauseClick` function and check if it is calling those function.

Comment: I updated the code, added to the child and parent console.log (different ones) and nothing was printed in the console. it's like the click event doesn't work. Iframe have different click event then (click)?

Comment: I do have error now in the console: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null .  It's not saying where the error is.

Comment: Looks like there is integration issue. Can update your changes in your answer ?

Comment: I updated and I think the problem is with the click event on the iframe. I searched on google but the results are only for angularJS and not angular 2+. Do you know how to emit click event inside the iframe? in angularJS onLoad()

Comment: How can you declare the same variable twice. Check your question.  `@Output() clicked = new EventEmitter();

  clicked: boolean = false;`